# .ALO/ALA file importing troubles

Tags: import, file-format

I am trying to import .ALO and or .ALA files that came from a .MEG file from the game 8-bit armies so I can edit the unit models or at least convert the file. I downloaded an .ALO/.ALA importer add on however when I try to import I get the error;

```
>Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\addons\io_alamo_tools\import_alo.py", line 918, in execute
    deleteRoot()
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\addons\io_alamo_tools\import_alo.py", line 775, in deleteRoot
    armature.select_set(True)  # select the skeleton
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'select_set'

location: <unknown location>:-1<
```

I even downloaded an ALO viewer that is used for galaxy at war ALO filles but no luck.

Comment: Best to ask the addon author since it's not part of Blender. Also make sure that the addon is written for the version of blender that you're using.

Comment: or on the contrary, uses the version of Blender for which the addon was created. You can see which version an addon is made for by looking for the "bl_info" header in its main file, it contains many info including the Blender version it is made for. See [example](https://i.imgur.com/HrwtqRd.jpeg).